# Unable to pass string parameter (multiline) to remote script using SSH

Tags: bash

I’m trying to run a script on a remote machine but I’m facing issue with the parameter that I’m passing to that script. I am passing a variable which is a string containing multiline as input.

The main script is named *parent.sh* which calls *child.sh* on remote machine. This *child.sh* is actually copied to the remote machine and then executed on that machine.

```
$ cat parent.sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/scp /home/tom/child.sh harry@remote_server:
printf "Key in parent script: $key\n\n"
/usr/bin/ssh -t harry@remote_server "sudo sh -c '/home/harry/child.sh '$key''"


$ cat child.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Key in child: $1"
```

Input:

```
key has the following content:
fruit=apple
vegetable=potato
```

Output:

```
Key in parent script: fruit=apple
vegetable=potato

Key in child: fruit=apple
```

Problem is that in the child script's output, i'm only getting the first line but not the second line (`vegetable=potato`). I tried few combinations of single and double quotes but nothing seems to be working. I would really love to know what blunder am i committing here and how can i rectify it.

Comment: Does this work: `"sudo sh -c '/home/harry/child.sh \"$key\"'"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @EtanReisner! :) Yes, it does work and i was just thinking how i missed giving that one a try. Thanks a lot! :) But now i'm confused why my syntax is not working. Why is it just passing one line instead of both? Or is it passing both but i'm not accepting it properly in child script?

Comment: Your syntax is leaving the expansion of `$key` *unquoted* in the arguments passed to `sh`. You probably have the second line available as `$2` with that. The "inner" single quotes you probably thought were quoting the expansion of `$key` are actually just ending the single quoted string and then starting a new (empty) single quoted string at the end of the command.

Comment: (@Etan Reisner) That was great! in my case `-t` was not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command should work:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -t harry@remote_server "sudo sh -c '/home/harry/child.sh \"$key\"'"
```

The key here is that you need the inner command to keep the value of `$key` quoted when it executes.

Your original command:

```
"sudo sh -c '/home/harry/child.sh '$key''"
```

which you probably thought was being read as:

```
"{sudo} {sh} {-c} {/home/harry/child.sh {$key}}"
```

is actually read as:

```
"{sudo} {sh} {-c} {/home/harry/child.sh }$key{}"
```

which leaves the expansion of `$key` unquoted and it then gets word-split and the newline becomes just another normal space. You probably have the second "line" available as `$2` in the script.

Comment: Well, i was about to request you to post your comments as answer. I'm glad you already read my mind and i'm even more happy with the way you explained it in this answer. The only thing i'm feeling bad about is that i can upvote it only once. :( Anyways, thanks a ton! :) This consumed a significant amount of time today but i'm glad i can sleep happily now.

Comment: And yes, you were right about $2 too. It did contain the missing line. Thanks! :)